# Laravel oauth using restAPI doesn't work but works in postman

Tags: php, laravel, oauth

I have 2 applications which both of them are using Laravel
oauth security.  These applications communicate through a restAPI 
When I request the oauth token through the postman it works fine but when I try it with the 1st application's (Guzzle) http post, it is unable to authenticate the
user. Both of them should be using the different db but when I switch
to mysql, the error message states that it is unable to connect to 1st
application's db. What went wrong here?

```
 protected function getAccessTokenMerchant()
{
    $client = new Client();
    $response = $client->POST("http://localhost/xxx/public/" . 'oauth/token', [
            'headers' => [
                'Accept' => 'application/json',
                'Content' => 'application/json'
            ],
            'json' => [
                'client_id' => "2",
                'client_secret' => "LlJ90SqW4IPSUfQGiLQVUzKtCr1FKMirS6bBxcf1",
                'grant_type' => 'client_credentials'
            ]
        ]
    );
    return $response->getBody();
}
```

the response of this code is 
Client error: `POST http://localhost/xxx/oauth/token` resulted in a `401 Unauthorized` response. when i use postman to do the request to http://localhost/xxx/oauth/token, i received the token

```
{
"token_type": "Bearer",
"expires_in": 31536000,
"access_token": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImp0aSI6IjAyYzFmZGQwNmE4MTM0MGM5ZDQwNjI3OWI3ZGJjN2E1NzdhMmJiMjllNjZkOTIzODE0Mjg2Y2IxNmVlM2ZiYjcwZDFlZTgxNmQwNDZlOWE4In0.eyJhdWQiOiIyIiwianRpIjoiMDJjMWZkZDA2YTgxMzQwYzlkNDA2Mjc5YjdkYmM3YTU3N2EyYmIyOWU2NmQ5MjM4MTQyODZjYjE2ZWUzZmJiNzBkMWVlODE2ZDA0NmU5YTgiLCJpYXQiOjE1NzE4NDQ4NDcsIm5iZiI6MTU3MTg0NDg0NywiZXhwIjoxNjAzMzgwODQ3LCJzdWIiOiIiLCJzY29wZXMiOltdfQ.WXIOIOVcacv4Cf-V8RlrlWpuIrDu0_cnoykxSQKtwAx1JxrK8dWsZqrxQbYsVU8Nt03apVpbtOEDhn32yIF7xhRuJHuw_p1x-waOJCQ2CDzcmkiumhDcc117CYrn3jrBaEDBKEpZSuI5ZW8-VqSWXmfpc18xjxESpAWej__wT78mKYtelZg00I2M5khJTAD2XaBsjoThdK0QuID6jtlMBaoZJEHzoEj-UKpuizOwvFXwbl6Plz3L_uuQqmKz64y8hfMhgZ8Zc70rkI_iLek7D1yEXn5EsZ5BH0qKgYsIYxyZMdojL4bhT8yjgB4KujZi8tHfM6iHthAgYYJ2WlIBQJ9lCpnGuP4xWyNGmN3HQZ4K5eM7pHkZLu3eEVrl-7JixC0HgDWos25m8_HIUnXaUs-dNDDsDMO0o57JB38ao-frUgfrAU6DgjYTEslmtS0SYpE6JoPTbBn7XYADy4VCP6J67dSm-J_Qbm8GFuyX_o57v43jH4tPFxq-ccnTlfzT-E6ApFsMhYAGli713TQUct2Y3VTQFVRMuDniMMKdsZT8XN4CLGbdN6tic9jQ5W_i-XfWL9vN_RSiXHROAF-KV8nxVj0n4GgycJ9DtV0-C3Qcpyz7Zbh_WrVPW5qsr5j5rrtWXsQ7VZOBCWLAyh4YXe_HSeOXqV-k202kcURZ0UQ"}
```

when i switch off the mySql server, getAccessTokenMerchant() function return error below:
Unknown database 'first_application_db' (SQL: select * from `client_credentials` where `code` = EWALLET limit 1)
which is not correct. it should check with the second_application_db not the first_application_db. any idea whats going on?

Comment: Add code to your question.

Comment: just added. was having problem posting the images just now @KonradSłotwiński

Comment: My guess is you are not using the token that is sent you by the server to use the "testMerchantAuth" method. The request that works with postman is only to retrieve the token. If you need further help you will have to post your code.

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the actual text of the code, not images. That makes it harder for us to see it.

Comment: @NesanMano the question is i havent retrieve the oauth from server. the testMerchantAuth method is for the system to request oauth token

Comment: @Hong I will have to look at your project and code in order to help you out.

Answer (score 0):

i found out the problem. my 2nd application somehow using client's db connection (1st application's db) that's why it unable to authenticate the oauth token. i solve by running `php artisan config:cache` and now it works